# SwiftyJSON looping through an array of JSON objects

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

```
[
    {
        "cont": 9714494770,
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Kakkad"
    },
    {
        "cont": 9714494770,
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ashish"
    }
]
```

The one above is a json array filled with JSON objects. I don't know how to parse through this with SwiftyJSON

Comment: JSON does not use typographical quotes `“ ... ”` :)

Comment: Just assume they are normal quotations

Answer (score 12):

Example from the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization) page, adapted to your data:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
for (index, object) in json {
    let name = object["name"].stringValue
    println(name)
}
```

Comment: Why can't it just be  for object in json? What does  for (index, object) in json  do differently that makes it work exactly? I've never seen that before. Thanks

Comment: You can use _ instead of index, but the index can be helpful for certain situations when you need to know where you are in the array. Or you can use key, object for dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `[{"id":"1", "name":"Kakkad", "cont":"9714494770"},{"id":"2", "name":"Ashish", "cont":"9714494770"}]` is assigned to a property named jsonData.

`let sampleJSON = JSON(data: jsonData)`

`let sampleArray = sampleJSON.array` sampleArray is an optional array of JSON objects.

`let firstDict = sampleArray[0]` firstDict is an optional JSON dict.

`let name = firstDict["name"]` is an optional JSON object

`let virtName = name.string` is a optional string (In this case "Kakkad").

`let realName = name.stringValue` realName is a string or an empty string.

You could also use:
`let longName = sampleJSON[0]["name"].stringValue`

After you initialize the JSON object with data all of the elements are JSON types until you convert them to a swift type.

- .string optional (string or null)
- .stringValue string or "" empty
  string
- .dict optional ([String: AnyObject] or null)
- .dictValue
  ([String: AnyObject] or String: AnyObject)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift4 I have updated the code from Moritz answer

```
    if let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tiles", ofType: "json") {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
                    let optData = try? JSON(data: data as Data)
                    guard let json = optData else {
                        return
                    }
//If it is a JSON array of objects
                    for (_, object) in json {
                        let name = object["name"].stringValue
                        print(name)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 or 4** code like this:

```
let json = JSON(yourData)
for (_, object) in json {
    let cont = object["cont"].stringValue
    print(cont)
}
```

You can put **index** instead of **_** if you use is anywhere in your code. If you don't use a variable, it's better to put _ (XCode also gives warnings).