# How to iterate JSON data using `for - in` in Swift using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am new to Swift, JSON and SwiftyJSON. Trying to read the json data and outputting it just to learn.  Below code works perfectly. However, I am thinking that it could be done using `for (key, json) in jsonData` someway; however, I cannot do it.  Any pointers?

```
func loadLocationData() {

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cityList", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            if json != JSON.null {

                if let cityArray = json["country"]["city"].array {

                    for city in cityArray {
                        DLog("\(city["Name"])")

                        if let districtArray = city["district"].array {

                            for district in districtArray {
                                DLog("-- \(district["Name"])")

                                if let placeArray = district["place"].array {

                                    for place in placeArray {

                                        DLog("  --  \(place["Name"])")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                print("could not get json from file, make sure that file contains valid json.")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not belong on Code Review as it is broken.  Code Review only takes questions with written, working code.  We would be glad to help you improve it once you get it working.

Comment: The OP says the code works - so Code review is broken? Just had a nosey over there and it seems OK - What's the problem with it? If you could let me know.. So I dont mistakenly send people there. Cheers.

Comment: The code is broken, so it is off topic at Code Review.  We have an off-topic reason specifically for broken code.  There is nothing wrong with Code Review.

Comment: @DavidWilson "however, I cannot do it." doesn't sound like it's working as intended just yet. The question is tackling a specific "problem" in the code and accordingly **on-topic** for Stack Overflow! This is basically a show-stopper when moving it to Code Review. In addition to that the goal of the code is (at least to me) not quite clear. OP is asking a specific question which may or may not be answered over at CR. I'd say that the question is simply better off here :)

Comment: using the guard keyword will reduce some of the nesting

Comment: Yes it will. However, I want to use `for (xxx, yyy) in json` somehow and can't figure out how. I think if done using `for - in` the code will be much cleaner. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Found an example, maybe this will put you on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757540/swiftyjson-looping-through-an-array-of-json-objects

Comment: Yes I have seen this, thank you. However, this example is for a single iteration. The JSON in my case have arrays within arrays within arrays. Which gets me confused. That is why I could write in array form but not in `for-in` form. I have updated the title for the question.